# LIBXML2 xmlNodeListGetRawString causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I am parsing a very big xml file of around 50 mb.
I am using a dom parser for that (specific reasons to use a DOM parser)
I take each xml attribute and store them in c++ structures that I have created.

The problem is after around 4 lakhs node value pairs creation xmlNodeListGetRawString libxml2 fails with segmentation fault as

## 0  0x00000039e487d5b5 in _int_malloc () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.2.2/lib/libc.so.6

## 1  0x00000039e488002c in malloc () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.2.2/lib/libc.so.6

## 2  0x00000039ed4ad909 in xmlStrndup () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.2.2/lib/libxml2.so.2

## 3  0x00000039ed4556a0 in xmlNodeListGetRawString () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.2.2/lib/libxml2.so.2

When I see the prog virtual memory consumption it is around 3.5 gb and its a 64 bit process as well as has ulimit for memory set to unlimited.
I am not able to understand the issue.
Is it memory consumption issue that is causing it to fail.